# No view found for id 0x7f0c0071

Tags: android

I really tried to find something here that solves this problem but I didn't find anything...

MainActivity.java:

```
package de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    SQLHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        db = new SQLHelper(this);

        addItemsFromDb();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.addUserMenu) {
           // AddUser addStudent = new AddUser();
           // FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            // manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, addStudent).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main, new AddClass()).commit();
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.addClassMenu){
            AddClass addClass = new AddClass();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, addClass).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void addItemsFromDb() {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        ArrayList<String> klassen = db.getAllKlassen();
        for (int i = 0; i < klassen.size(); i++) {
            menu.add(klassen.get(i));
        }


        // refreshing navigation drawer adapter
        for (int i = 0, count = navigationView.getChildCount(); i < count; i++) {
            final View child = navigationView.getChildAt(i);
            if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
                final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
                final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
                final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
                wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:id="@+id/include" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</RelativeLayout>
```

And i'll only provide my AddUser.java, because the AddClass.java is nearly the same:

```
package de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AddUser extends Fragment {


    public AddUser() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    EditText vorname, nachname;
    Button addstudent;
    Spinner spinner;
    SQLHelper db;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_user, container, false);

        vorname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.vorname);
        nachname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nachname);

        addstudent = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addStudent);

        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        db = new SQLHelper(getActivity());

        ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = db.getAllKlassen();


        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        addstudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vorname.setText("");
                nachname.setText("");
                if(db.addStudent(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), vorname.getText().toString(), nachname.getText().toString()) == true){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Der Benutzer " + vorname.getText().toString() + " " + nachname.getText().toString() + " wurde erfolgreich der Klasse " + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + " hinzugefügt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Da ist was schief gelaufen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

my fragment_adduser.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql.AddUser"
android:id="@+id/addStudentFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/vorname"
    android:hint="Vorname" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vorname"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/nachname"
    android:hint="Nachname" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nachname"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />

<Button
    android:text="Schüler hinzufügen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/addStudent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried it with a fresh fragment but it didn't worked aswell :(

Logcat Log:

```
12-1012:16:12.4904371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlE/FragmentManager:Noviewfoundforid0x7f0c0071(de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql:id/content_main)forfragmentAddClass{560ed4#0id=0x7f0c0071}
12-1012:16:12.4904371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlE/FragmentManager:Activitystate:
12-1012:16:12.4914371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:LocalFragmentActivity3469381State:
12-1012:16:12.4914371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mCreated=truemResumed=truemStopped=falsemReallyStopped=false
12-1012:16:12.4914371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mLoadersStarted=true
12-1012:16:12.4914371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:ActiveFragmentsin921187d:
12-1012:16:12.4914371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:#0:AddClass{560ed4#0id=0x7f0c0071}
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mFragmentId=#7f0c0071mContainerId=#7f0c0071mTag=null
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mState=1mIndex=0mWho=android:fragment:0mBackStackNesting=1
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mAdded=truemRemoving=falsemFromLayout=falsemInLayout=false
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mHidden=falsemDetached=falsemMenuVisible=truemHasMenu=false
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mRetainInstance=falsemRetaining=falsemUserVisibleHint=true
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{921187dinHostCallbacks{63bb372}}
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@63bb372
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:AddedFragments:
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:#0:AddClass{560ed4#0id=0x7f0c0071}
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:BackStackIndices:
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:#0:BackStackEntry{44453c3#0}
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:FragmentManagermiscstate:
12-1012:16:12.4924371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@63bb372
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@63bb372
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:mCurState=5mStateSaved=falsemDestroyed=false
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:ViewHierarchy:
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{e6f4440V.E........0,0-1080,1920}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.widget.LinearLayout{5abbf79V.E........0,0-1080,1794}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.view.ViewStub{f0d94beG.E........0,0-0,0#10203a9android:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.widget.FrameLayout{50e691fV.E........0,0-1080,1794}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout{824646cV.E........0,0-1080,1794#7f0c0059app:id/action_bar_root}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat{59fda35G.E........0,0-0,0#7f0c005aapp:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{38a3ecaV.E........0,0-1080,1794#1020002android:id/content}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{b3a783bVFED....F..0,0-1080,1794#7f0c006dapp:id/drawer_layout}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout{1295b58V.ED.......0,0-1080,1794}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout{7c6f7baV.E........0,63-1080,210}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{680e4b1V.E........0,0-1080,147#7f0c006fapp:id/toolbar}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{c757d96V.ED.......189,38-596,109}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton{24e5d17VFED..C....0,0-147,147}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView{284d504V.E........975,0-1080,147}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton{8e1aedVFED..C....0,10-105,136}
12-1012:16:12.4934371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.widget.RelativeLayout{30e566bV.E........0,210-1080,1794#7f0c0070app:id/include}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.design.widget.NavigationView{903dd22I.E........-735,0-0,1794#7f0c006eapp:id/nav_view}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView{e51b3b3VFED.V.....0,0-735,1794#7f0c0077app:id/design_navigation_view}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.widget.LinearLayout{cfc3d70V.E........0,0-735,441#7f0c0076app:id/navigation_header_container}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.widget.LinearLayout{6be78e9V.E........0,0-735,420}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{526a96eV.ED.......42,66-168,234#7f0c0084app:id/imageView}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{229d80fV.ED.......42,234-693,327}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{63fc09cV.ED.......42,327-519,378#7f0c0085app:id/textView}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/FragmentManager:android.view.View{a7cbaa5V.ED.......0,1794-1080,1920#1020030android:id/navigationBarBackground}
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlD/AndroidRuntime:ShuttingdownVM
12-1012:16:12.4944371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlE/AndroidRuntime:FATALEXCEPTION:main
    Process:de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql,PID:4371
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Noviewfoundforid0x7f0c0071(de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql:id/content_main)forfragmentAddClass{560ed4#0id=0x7f0c0071}
        atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
        atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
        atandroid.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
        atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
        atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
        atandroid.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod)
        atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-1012:16:12.4941555-1962/system_processW/ActivityManager:Forcefinishingactivityde.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql/.MainActivity
12-1012:16:12.4981214-1616/?D/gralloc_ranchu:gralloc_alloc:format1andusage0x333implycreationofhostcolorbuffer

[12-1012:16:12.5011555:1962D/]
HostConnection::get()NewHostConnectionestablished0x7fc54b5b7360,tid1962
12-1012:16:12.5111255-1621/?D/AudioFlinger:mixer(0xf44c0000)throttleend:throttletime(55)
12-1012:16:12.5131214-1214/?E/EGL_emulation:tid1214:eglCreateSyncKHR(1660):error0x3004(EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
12-1012:16:12.5771555-1962/system_processD/gralloc_ranchu:gralloc_unregister_buffer:exitingHostConnection(isbuffer-handlingthread)
12-1012:16:12.6711555-1606/system_processI/OpenGLRenderer:InitializedEGL,version1.4
12-1012:16:12.6881214-1617/?D/gralloc_ranchu:gralloc_alloc:format1andusage0x900implycreationofhostcolorbuffer
12-1012:16:12.6941555-1606/system_processE/EGL_emulation:tid1606:eglSurfaceAttrib(1165):error0x3009(EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-1012:16:12.6941555-1606/system_processW/OpenGLRenderer:FailedtosetEGL_SWAP_BEHAVIORonsurface0x7fc54b53fac0,error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-1012:16:12.6961214-1329/?D/gralloc_ranchu:gralloc_alloc:format1andusage0x900implycreationofhostcolorbuffer
12-1012:16:12.6981214-1329/?D/gralloc_ranchu:gralloc_alloc:format1andusage0x900implycreationofhostcolorbuffer
12-1012:16:13.0841555-1569/system_processW/ActivityManager:ActivitypausetimeoutforActivityRecord{32c16b2u0de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql/.MainActivityt338f}
12-1012:16:13.1171214-1579/?D/gralloc_ranchu:gralloc_alloc:format1andusage0x900implycreationofhostcolorbuffer
12-1012:16:13.1251950-2080/com.android.launcher3E/EGL_emulation:tid2080:eglSurfaceAttrib(1165):error0x3009(EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-1012:16:13.1251950-2080/com.android.launcher3W/OpenGLRenderer:FailedtosetEGL_SWAP_BEHAVIORonsurface0x7fc5574928c0,error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-1012:16:13.1261214-1329/?D/gralloc_ranchu:gralloc_alloc:format1andusage0x900implycreationofhostcolorbuffer
12-1012:16:13.1311214-1329/?D/gralloc_ranchu:gralloc_alloc:format1andusage0x900implycreationofhostcolorbuffer
12-1012:16:13.6661950-2080/com.android.launcher3W/OpenGLRenderer:IncorrectlycalledbuildLayeronView:ShortcutAndWidgetContainer,destroyinglayer...
12-1012:16:13.6661950-2080/com.android.launcher3W/OpenGLRenderer:IncorrectlycalledbuildLayeronView:ShortcutAndWidgetContainer,destroyinglayer...
12-1012:16:14.8624371-4371/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsqlI/Process:Sendingsignal.PID:4371SIG:9
12-1012:16:14.8781555-1606/system_processE/Surface:getSlotFromBufferLocked:unknownbuffer:0x7fc548597ce0
12-1012:16:14.8871555-1708/system_processE/JavaBinder:!!!FAILEDBINDERTRANSACTION!!!(parcelsize=104)
12-1012:16:14.8871555-1708/system_processW/InputMethodManagerService:GotRemoteExceptionsendingsetActive(false)notificationtopid4371uid10041
12-1012:16:14.8891555-1708/system_processE/JavaBinder:!!!FAILEDBINDERTRANSACTION!!!(parcelsize=104)
12-1012:16:14.9081255-1621/?D/AudioFlinger:mixer(0xf44c0000)throttleend:throttletime(11)
12-1012:16:14.9221555-1625/system_processD/GraphicsStats:Buffercount:3
12-1012:16:14.9221555-1917/system_processI/WindowState:WINDEATH:Window{7880644u0de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql.MainActivity}
12-1012:16:14.9221555-1917/system_processW/WindowManager:Force-removingchildwinWindow{662c9bau0PopupWindow:81e55c2}fromcontainerWindow{7880644u0de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql/de.thejakekols.brunoflo.teamgennewsql.MainActivity}
12-1012:16:14.9261555-1625/system_processW/WindowManager:Failedlookingupwindow
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Requestedwindowandroid.os.BinderProxy@408fae5doesnotexist
atcom.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8733)
atcom.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8724)
atcom.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1209)
atandroid.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:558)
12-1012:16:14.9261555-1625/system_processI/WindowState:WINDEATH:null
```

I'm new into Android :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID specified on an `<include>` tag overrides the ID of the root `View` in the inflated layout. This means that the `RelativeLayout` you're using to hold your `Fragment`'s `View` does not have ID `content_main` after inflation. It has ID `include`, so the `FragmentManager` can't find the `ViewGroup` for the ID specified in the `FragmentTransaction`.

You can see this in your hierarchy listing:

```
android.widget.RelativeLayout{30e566b V.E..... ... 0,210-1080,1794 #7f0c0070 app:id/include}
```

Simply remove `android:id="@+id/include"` from the `<include>` tag in the `app_bar_main` layout.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have done mistake in the code

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_user, container, false);
```

Please check the inflated layout is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot to provide the fragment_add_user.xml. I'm not sure where and what exactly to check. Maybe you can help me.